# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 51644, 29, 32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a CNN 1D model for binary classification and the file I used is csv file How can I solve this kind of error?....Thanks in advance

this is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9jT6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm7dY.png)

the error is:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 51644, 29, 32)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5hG9.png)

Comment: Your data is 2D (a picture like), while you are trying to use a model that accepts 1D objects (sequences). You either need to use a model that accepts the type of data you want to work with, or you need to convert your data to fit your model.

Comment: Please post the real textual code, instead of snapshots.

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', low_memory=False)
data = data.drop([64555], axis=0)
y = data.label
x = data.drop('label', axis=1)

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 5, padding='valid', input_shape=(train.shape[0], train.shape[1], 1), activation='relu', strides=1 ))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 5, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, padding='valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: model.fit(train, train_label, epochs=3, batch_size=32)
score = model.evaluate(test, test_label, batch_size=128)

Comment: Actually not like that, I meant to post the code with the question itself. Please edit your question and copy-paste the code there. After pasting the code select the code and click on `{}` button, the code will be formatted itself. For difficulty see details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210852/659522 ...Also I have posted an answer, hope it will help....thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `input_shape` from `(train_shape[0], train_shape[1], 1)` to `(train_shape[1], 1)`. As you are using `Conv1D`, assuming you are working with a sequence data. So in this case `train_shape[0]` is the `batch_size`, `train_shape[1]` is the `number of time-steps` i.e, the `sequence length` and the last `1` is the `number of features` in each time-stamp.

The important thing is that, `keras` doesn't require you to input the `batch_size`, it is auto-defaulted to `None` and the input shape becomes `(None, train_shape[1], 1)` automatically, such that it can work with any batch sizes, so no need to input the first dimension. But if you want to input the `batch size` yourself, then use `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape`.

Also use `softmax` function in the output layer instead of `sigmoid`, as you have more than one neurons in the output layer.

Comment: i changed input shape to (train.shape[1],1) but also i received an error as follows:  ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 23, 10) are incompatible with line of ( model.fit(train, train_label, epochs=3,)  )

Comment: i have only two output (normal or malware) for this reason i used sigmoid

Comment: @mohammadalani but you have added `10` neurons in the output dense layer, why? It requires you to have `10` classes. For *binary* classification either use only `1` neuron if you want to use `sigmoid` or use `2` neurons with `softmax`.

Comment: thank you i edited this line with 2 neurons

Comment: are there any other notes ?

Comment: which is the best loss function with my code?

Comment: Ok, you are now using `softmax` + `2 neurons in output`. Now, tell me about the variable `train_label`. Is this variable one-hot encoded? Or just label encoded? You may give me an example of how a *single* output variable looks like which you are passing, I shall understand the rest.

Comment: no it is not one-hot encoded

Comment: Ok, that means label encoded. So, change your loss function from `categorical_crossentropy` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, the reason is here: https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class

Comment: i will send to you the error that i received :

Comment: line 716, in update_state
>>>     y_true = tf.cast(y_true, self._dtype)
>>>

Comment: with line of model.fit()

Comment: @mohammadalani the error message is not too intuitive. Are your output labels numeric? Or string like - "normal", "malware"?

Comment: it is numeric like 0 or 1

Comment: @mohammadalani I think the error you are getting is too deviated from the posted question. Please ask another question if you feel so, with code and error details. Thanks.

Comment: data type of train_label is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @mohammadalani try with a `single neuron` in the output `dense` layer with activation `sigmoid` i.e, `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` and `loss = 'binary_crossentropy'`, ...see if it helps.